# render image on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a way for me to render the image I selected in angularjs... 
like how you upload picture here in stackoverflow... when you select a picture the picture will render first before you can upload...

I'm really new to this so bear with me..

**controller**

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(parameter){
    console.log(parameter[0]);
    $scope.profilePic = parameter[0];
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="{{profilePic}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <input type="file" name="image_path" class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

there's also a problem in using `ng-change` it gives me an error.. anonymous function error..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-src` instead of `src` in

```
<img ng-src="{{profilePic}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
```

`ng-src` will suspend the image source assignment until image is available

check this [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jo7rU4Ri4dRni6YJ4BM6?p=preview) it working the way you want, hope it helps

i have just added a `readURL(input)` function which uses `FileReader` and converts the uploaded image to it's readable format

Comment: but how can I pass it from the controller?... my function `uploadfile` doesn't let me change the value of `profilePic`..

Comment: and one thing is that... when I tried to select a picture it doesn't give me any path...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see u using `ng-change` u are using `<input type="file" name="image_path" class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"  />`. U can try changing `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"` to `ng-change="uploadFile(this.files)"`

Comment: as you can see on my question I have tried using `ng-change` but gives me an error `anonymous function`